# Unable to deploy artifacts

Tags: cloudbees

I get the following when trying to deploy artifcats from within my job:

```
[ERROR] uniqueVersion == false is not anymore supported in maven 3
[INFO] Deployment in dav:https://repository-xinco.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot (id=cloudbees-private-repository,uniqueVersion=false)
Deploying the main artifact Card-Game-Extension-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
Downloading: dav:https://repository-xinco.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/simple/server/Card-Game-Extension/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Uploading: https://repository-xinco.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/simple/server/Card-Game-Extension/1.0-SNAPSHOT/Card-Game-Extension-1.0-20120820.205113-1.pom
Uploading: https://repository-xinco.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/simple/server/Card-Game-Extension/1.0-SNAPSHOT/Card-Game-Extension-1.0-20120820.205113-1.pom
ERROR: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact simple.server:Card-Game-Extension:pom:1.0-20120820.205113-1 from/to cloudbees-private-repository (dav:https://repository-xinco.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot): Failed to transfer file: https://repository-xinco.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/simple/server/Card-Game-Extension/1.0-SNAPSHOT/Card-Game-Extension-1.0-20120820.205113-1.pom. Return code is: 401
org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact simple.server:Card-Game-Extension:pom:1.0-20120820.205113-1 from/to cloudbees-private-repository (dav:https://repository-xinco.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot): Failed to transfer file: https://repository-xinco.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/simple/server/Card-Game-Extension/1.0-SNAPSHOT/Card-Game-Extension-1.0-20120820.205113-1.pom. Return code is: 401
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:141)
    at hudson.maven.reporters.MavenArtifactRecord.deploy(MavenArtifactRecord.java:182)
    at hudson.maven.RedeployPublisher.perform(RedeployPublisher.java:158)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:707)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:682)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$RunnerImpl.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:997)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:629)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1433)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:481)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:238)
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact simple.server:Card-Game-Extension:pom:1.0-20120820.205113-1 from/to cloudbees-private-repository (dav:https://repository-xinco.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot): Failed to transfer file: https://repository-xinco.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/simple/server/Card-Game-Extension/1.0-SNAPSHOT/Card-Game-Extension-1.0-20120820.205113-1.pom. Return code is: 401
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:280)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:211)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:443)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:137)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact simple.server:Card-Game-Extension:pom:1.0-20120820.205113-1 from/to cloudbees-private-repository (dav:https://repository-xinco.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot): Failed to transfer file: https://repository-xinco.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/simple/server/Card-Game-Extension/1.0-SNAPSHOT/Card-Game-Extension-1.0-20120820.205113-1.pom. Return code is: 401
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:950)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:940)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$PutTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:837)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.put(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:467)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:274)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Failed to transfer file: https://repository-xinco.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/simple/server/Card-Game-Extension/1.0-SNAPSHOT/Card-Game-Extension-1.0-20120820.205113-1.pom. Return code is: 401
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:379)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.put(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:287)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.webdav.WebDavWagon.put(WebDavWagon.java:332)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$PutTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:811)
    ... 16 more
[INFO] Deployment failed after 0.74 sec
Build step 'Deploy artifacts to my Private CloudBees Repository' changed build result to FAILURE
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Is there anything to set up in the repository I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a repository permission issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `Deploy artifacts to my Private CloudBees Repository` publisher.

You need to enable the `Assign unique versions to snapshots` option on the `Advanced` options for that plugin.

Once you do that it should deploy just fine.

Comment: Thanks, this is the most useful answer for this question.

Comment: That's not the problem. This error from the console should be more of a warning really since the build still succeeds with it. The real problem is the permission of the Private CloudBess Repository.

Answer (score 0):

"uniqueVersion == false is not anymore supported in maven 3", even being reported as an ERROR, won't stop the deployment.

This seems to be a configuration issue in your account, will follow-up on https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/tickets/5055